# Female sword fighter offering herself to her opponent if he wins

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

In the early 1980s I read a fantasy short story in which a female fighter told the male protagonist that he could "have her" if he defeated her in a sword fight. I read the story in German, but very likely it was translated from English. It was published in an anthology, very likely one of the ones listed below.

As I remember it, the story (or at least the encounter and fight between the man and woman) took place in an inn in a Conan-like world, but I might misremember.

Unfortunately, that is all I remember. I want to know how it ended :-)

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  This is really very little to go on; do you remember _anything_ else?  Did they have armour?  Shields?  Was it in a magazine or a book?

Comment: This is a very common trope; https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BestHerToBedHer

Comment: A Red Sonja story?

Comment: per @Moriarty comment - it seems like Red Sonja though obviously it is a very common trope - and alas does not work in the opposite direction in my experience.  Red Sonja scene https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ChqDVHT-NtA

Comment: I can name an English-language fantasy short story which matches your description of the basic plot. It came out in the 1980s, but -- according to the ISFDB website -- that story (and the entire anthology) was only ever published in two languages: 1) English, and 2) Italian. No German translation. If you are *certain* that you originally saw the story in German in the 1980s, then I'm reluctant to type out a full Answer if I would just be wasting our time on a coincidence.

Comment: In the game Witcher 3 there is a quest where a swordswoman offers herself to anyone who can beat her.  And obviously Wither 3 isn't the answer, but the game tends to take its cues from well-established cultural / fairy tale tropes, so I think it's pretty important that you try and recall any detail other than that.  There must be something you can remember.  After all, if there isn't, how would you even know if a suggestion was the correct one.

Comment: @Lorendiac Are you thinking of a story by Jennifer Roberson?

Comment: @mkennedy Yes. But as I said, if it can't be the right one because of the language issue, then I don't want to take the time to dig out my copy, reread it, and write up a full Answer to post on here.

Comment: OP, Lorendiac and I are thinking of a story by Jennifer Roberson called the The Lady and the Tiger. Tiger is a famous male sword-dancer in a desert region with claw marks on his face. The Lady is a female swordsinger from a cold(er) northern climate. They're very evenly matched. I think they both wear harnesses with scabbards on their backs as opposed to their waists. ISFDB doesn't show it as translated to German, but ISFDB doesn't have everything either.

Comment: @mkennedy Good that you give the author and title. In fact that story has been published as "Sandtiger und Del" in *Wolfsschwester: Magische Geschichten II*, the German edition of the anthology *Sword and Sorceress II*, edited by Marion Zimmer Bradley. I remember both the English and the German editions of that anthology series, so I could have read either one. Your brief description sounds very much like the story I am looking for. I'll try to get a copy of that book and read the story. That may take some time, but I will let you know. Thank you!

Comment: @mkennedy I had an opportunity to read Jennifer Roberson's "The Lady and the Tiger" yesterday. My first reading has been so long ago that re-reading it didn't evoke any more memories or emotions. Everything seems to fit, and I'm quite sure that it is the story I am looking for, but at the same time I didn't like the story much and don't understand why it might have stayed in my mind for so long. It must have been my adolescent obsession with sex for which the story provided some projection surface. [contd.]

Comment: [contd.] The thighs of the female swordfighter get a lot of the author's attention and that the narrator-protagonist might "win her" could have appealed to my younger virgin self. Thank you, @mkennedy, for not showing the reluctance of Lorendiac and disclosing the author and name of the story you were thinking of. I guess my question has been answered, even if the answer didn't provide the satisfying resolution to a decade-long riddle I was hoping for.

Comment: This trope goes back at least a thousand years, to [the story of](https://literature.stackexchange.com/a/5970/17) Digenes Akrites and Maximou in Byzantine Greek epic poetry.

Comment: I'm sure you saw, but just to make sure:  the Roberson Tiger & Del story was expanded into a novel & the series has 7 books now (and one planned).

Answer (score 5):

F M Busby's [*For a Daughter*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?95821)?

It doesn't take place at an inn, though, but it was translated into German.

Comment: Actually that is a story I did read, and in German, but it is not the one I am looking for. Thank you nevertheless!